# Is it possible to force a page size/layout when printing?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, printing, zebra-printers

I have one of the strangest problems I may have encountered.

We have a Zebra armband printer that we're trying to print to from IE. If the printer is set as the default printer everything is A-OK.

However, if *another* printer is selected as the default printer with, say a page size of 8.5"x11", then if you select the Zebra it tries to print in any number of absolutely awful ways. Either it tries to print 11 armbands (one for each inch), or instead of printing with the correct orientation, it prints 90 degrees off, which trims off the sides of what we're trying to print.

No good.

I have tried the following

## A

```
    <style media="print">
        @page {
            size: 1in 11in;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .page {
        }   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -moz-trnsform:rotate(-90deg);
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Micorsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        }
    </style>
```

## B

```
    <style>
        @page {
            size: 1in 11in;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
```

## C

```
    <style>
        @media print {
            body {
                width: 11in;
                height: 1in;
            }
        }

        @page {
            size: 1in 11in;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
```

All of these options failed. Of interesting note, option C actually completely failed to print. The job was sent to the printer, but the printer just said, "Yeah, right. I'm not printing that garbage."

So... is there a way to force my page to print properly? Bonus points for cross-browser compatibility, but at minimum I need to support IE.

Comment: i asked something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268651/unable-to-insert-stylesheet-script-into-window-open)

Comment: @jbutler483 The styling on the new page is fine - the problem is just that when changing to a different printer it gets confused and tells it that the area to be printed is 8.5"x11" - which is a total lie, but the Zebra believes it.

Comment: Unless there's an issue with the printer. check the printer docs, and see if there's any info there. I was working with a dot matrix printer a while back and strange things were happening with it. It could be that it needs to 'clear cache' or 'update readings' or the like.

Comment: @jbutler483 It's reliable across different printers and different host machines, so I don't think it's a caching issue. The problem (I think) is really with how Windows print works, which is apparently in the stupidest way possible. When you open up the print preview window you can see this happen. It is impossible to change the size of the page you're printing to something smaller than the printer's specified page size. So what I'm *trying* to do is force the page size before it makes it to the print settings in hopes that it will use that.

Comment: Sorry: What I meant was with the printer itself, not on the host machine. But printers are very much make/model specific, which makes things 1000x worse/harder to debug.

Comment: could you 'trick' the printer into thinking it had a different sized page loaded (via a print command?)

Comment: Looks like I figured out (part of) the problem. The printer is getting switched to portrait instead of landscape, it's getting unprintable areas(margins?) and the size of the armband is getting set incorrectly.