# Print Preview of gridview is not center allign

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to print one gridview . For that I gave a button and on button click I call javascript for printing tha grid.

```
 function doPrint() {
            var prtContent = document.getElementById('<%= grdHistoricalData.ClientID %>');
           prtContent.border = 0; //set no border here
           var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=50,top=100,border=1px,width=1000,textAlign=center,height=1000,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
           WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.outerHTML);
           WinPrint.document.close();
           WinPrint.focus();
           WinPrint.print();
           WinPrint.close();
       }
```

This code is working fine but only thing is that print preview of gridview data is displaying left align.Normally Girdview Data is showing center align but when we print data shows in left align.
Gridview normal appearance 
[image]

Print Preview of Gridview

[image]

Please help to do center align in print preview of Gridview.

Comment: css stylesheet is outside of `prtContent`. You can either include inline styles into your GridView (ugly solution) or `open` a small document with desirable stylesheet and insert (not `document.write`) in it.

Comment: Another solution is to add `media=print` css in which `display:none` whatever you don't want. In fact I use both approach on different pages.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev How can include inline styles in Gridview.I tried with HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  in gridview but it is not working.

Comment: The second approach is preferable. Do not open a window. Just add `<style media="print"` to the page and `display:none` or / and `border:none;margin:0` to everything which shouldn't be printed. It requires some work.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Where should I call this style in gridview ?

Comment: this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269356/17447 get back to us if problem persists. this happens because the css is not applied on the new opened window.

Comment: @Naveen just got solution for this , I need to put one configuration in gridview <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> . it is working with this :)

Comment: @vim: behind the scenes, if you view source you can see that it will inject inline css into the table.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions I use in different circumstances.
1) external file. Load a small file to a `iframe` and call for data from parent.

```
<!--print.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Printer version</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var a = this.parent.getContent();
            document.body.innerHTML = a;
        }
        function printMe() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>
    <link href="/Styles/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Parent document.

```
<div id="divPrint" style="display:none;">
<div class="popup">
   <div style="overflow:hidden;">Printer Version
    <div style="float:right;">
        <input type="button" ID="btnPrnClose" value="X" onclick="return closePrint()" />
     </div>
    </div>
        <iframe  id="frPrint" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function getContent() {
            return '<div>' + 
'<div class="right no-print" onclick="printMe();" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Print"> \
    <img alt="Print" src="/images/printer.png" /></div>' + document.getElementById('gvOuterContainer').innerHTML+ '</div>';
        }
        function closePrint() {
            document.getElementById('divPrint').style.display = 'none';
        }
        function PrintMessage() {
           document.getElementById('divPrint').style.display = '';
           document.getElementById('frPrint').src = "print.html?a=" + Math.random();//force no-cache
           return false;
        }
</script>
```

2) Print from the page.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    *
    {
        border: none!important;
    }
    .noprint,.popup
    {
        display: none!important;
    }
    #scrollContainer
    {
        width: auto!important;
    }
    .pop-show
    {
        display: table!important;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%!important;
        z-index: 100;
    }
/* and so on */
</style>
```

Details may differ.

Comment: just got one property of gridview.that works <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">

Answer (score 1):

Finally got answer , I need to set gridview property that resolve this issue

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
```